# Deploying EAR file in websphere

Tags: java, maven, websphere

After building my maven project, the ear file gets created under target folder. Each time I have to login to websphere console and deploy the latest ear file. Is there is any way so that the latest EAR gets deploy automatically into the server.

I am using:

Tool - Eclipse Indigo
Server - Websphere

Let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: I sometimes use a bat file which copies the ear from the target to the deploy folder assuming you are working in development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebSphere Application Server administrative script and ant command.

Script will have the very simple command  `AdminApp.install('application.ear', ['-server', 'server_name'])`

Create ant ask to call your script.
Add ant maven plugin into pom and call created ant task.

You can see more options in [WebSphere documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/txml_callappinstall.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Maven Cargo plugin.

https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Home.html

I use the Cargo plugin to deploy to various servers such as Tomcat, JBoss AS and more recently WildFly.

Let me know if it works for you.

```
clean package cargo:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

IBM has published eclipse plugin for websphere : 
https://davanum.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/was-7-0-eclipse-plugin-ibm-websphere-application-server-7-0/
In the configuration I use, Maven does not deploy the ear itself, it should configure Eclipse projects to resolve dependencies, then Eclipse takes care of EAR build and deploy.